# Simulator Not playing Video

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have new Mac mini installed 10.10.1, installed Xcode 6.1.1, Whenever I am trying to Play video in my Application it buffers and suddenly stops & shows alert message “Unable to Play Video”. Its happening all time, I have tried to visit in simulator setting & its Privacy option but nothing found which can help me, I have tried to do googling but not found problem related stuff.

On Device, Player working properly.

[image]

So If anyone has faced this problem, please help to resolve, Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Some of the function on Simulator has been stopped from newer `Xcode` like mail with attachment, video selection from `UIImagePicker`, Playing video with `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: @vijeesh : Thanks, its not code related problem, video are getting played on device and on other machine mac simulator, problem is system specific, on new mac only.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. this problem is because of Input devices in mac mini. goto system preferences -> sound -> input tab to verify.

connect some input device (like headset or something) to your mac mini and play the video. then it worked fine for me in simulator too.

Comment: It should work for device without any input device as previously it was working.

Comment: For me, I changed my output from multi-output to headphones, and that solved it.